Sum values from all rows between specific characters
I have got formulas in lets say column C, that looks like that:

Is it actually possible to sum values that are in parentheses from all rows in one column and display it in one cell?
I was trying to use formulatext with mid and i it worked but just for one cell.

If only one instance of parentheses per cell this should work:
=SUM(1*IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(FORMULATEXT(A:A),"("),")"),0))

Result:


It works! But the file that i'm using it in, may be opened in older excel versions and unfortunately older versions doesn't support "text before" and "text after". Is there any other way to do it? I tried =SUM(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1), FIND("(", FORMULATEXT(A1))+1, FIND(")", FORMULATEXT(A1))-FIND("(", FORMULATEXT(A1))-1)) But as i said, it works only for one cell.

This could be rather challenging if you need this done with formulae in older versions of Excel:

Formula in C1:
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1:A3),"(","</s><s>|"),")","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'|')]"),2,99))

This should work as long as there is a single value between parantheses. If more, then you can't feed the entire range of cells at once, but you can still do it per cell.

Hmm that's strange, if i open formula in excel (Microsoft 365) it works as expected but if i open the same file in Excel 2013 formula works only for the first cell and the result is 1 (instead of 65). Thank you anyway :)

@Bartek123 you will need to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER while exiting the edit mode.

@MayukhBhattacharya so its still not working. When i press this combination while exiting edit mode result changes and then formula takes only first cell into account.

@Bartek123 dont have access to Excel 2013 but it should work, can you show a screenshot how it is missing out the other cells.

Try pressing the combination you mentioned even in the newer Excel. After saving the formula normally by pressing enter (according to JvdV's screenshot) the result is 65 but if you press ctrl+ shift + enter the result is 1 and it doesn't affect other cells.
